# backbone collection length is 0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

app code section:

```
handleFileSelect: function(evt) {


var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
        var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
        collection.on('complete',this.renderImg);
        var x = 5;

for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
            var f = files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
```

Closure to capture the file information.

```
reader.onload = (function (theFile,collection) {
                return function (e) {
```

add models in collection

```
collection.add(new Backbone.Model({title:theFile.name,src:e.target.result}));       

    };


     })(f,collection);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
            return collection;
        }
```

---

collection is returned, and length is 0, ie no models in the collection, please?

Comment: `onload` is asynchronous.

Comment: ie function returned before adding to the collection of models?

Comment: Exactly. If you do `console.log` of the returned collection in Chrome, you should be able to inspect it. You'll see that the length did change, but slightly after returning the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collection is a big object with various methods and properties. Models in collections are located in  setting collection.models. Check such property: collection.models.length() - this property must be not a 0.